# How to print all keystrokes on screen with JS?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a hangman type of game and I got the keystrokes to display on screen, but they seem to overwrite each other each time I hit a key.

How can I display every keystroke in order on screen?

```
//Possible words to guess and guesses left
var words = ['jason', 'kaitlyn', 'lora', 'matthew'],
    guessesLeft = 9;

//Computer picks random word to guess
function getItem() {
  document.getElementById("wordGuess").innerHTML = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}

//This code captures the keypress and prints it out on the screen
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event,
      charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which,
      lettersGuessed = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML = lettersGuessed;
  document.getElementById("guessesLeft").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

  guessesLeft--;

  // var userGuess = prompt("What word do you guess?");
  // if (words.indexOf(userGuess) > -1){
  //    alert("Your guess is correct.")
  // }else{
  //    alert("Your guess is wrong.")
  // }

  if (guessesLeft === -1) {
    alert("You Loose!");
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you think `document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML = lettersGuessed;` does every time it's called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overwrite is occuring upon assigning `lettersGuessed` rather than appending them.

**[Assigning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)**: (wrong behavior)

```
document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML = lettersGuessed;
```

**[Appending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2xk8y0c(v=vs.94).aspx)**: (correct behavior)

```
document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed;
```

After that you can see the following result:

```js
//Possible words to guess
 var words = ['jason', 'kaitlyn', 'lora', 'matthew'];



 //Computer picks random word to guess
 function getItem() {
   document.getElementById("wordGuess").innerHTML = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
 }

 //This code captures the keypress and prints it out on the screen
 var guessesLeft = 9;

 document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
   var evt = evt || window.event;
   var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
   var lettersGuessed = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
   document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed;
   document.getElementById("guessesLeft").innerHTML = guessesLeft;
   guessesLeft--;

   // var userGuess = prompt("What word do you guess?");
   // if (words.indexOf(userGuess) > -1){
   //  alert("Your guess is correct.")
   // }else{
   //  alert("Your guess is wrong.")
   // }


   if (guessesLeft === -1) {
     alert("You Loose!");
   }
 };
```

```html
<!-- Example HTML code --->
<div id="wordGuess">abcdefg</div>
<div id="lettersGuessed"></div>
<div id="guessesLeft"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting `#lettersGuessed` on each key press. You should do something like:

```
document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed;
```

But I would suggest adding the letters to an array and checking everything from there.