# how can I allow a user to write something into a text box with html or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner programmer and I want to allow someone using my program to be able to type a key on the keyboard and have it be typed out on the screen, but I want it to be normal typing that you can copy and paste and do everything a normal typing function can do. I haven't tried anything because I couldn't think of any ideas for what to do

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Without a textbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442752/how-to-print-all-keystrokes-on-screen-with-js

Answer (score 1):

For this you simply do a textarea tag like so. More info about this can be found on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Type here
</textarea>
```